# chart control image visual basic vb .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I like to embed an image on the Microsoft chart control so when the save chart function is called, it has logo on the jpg that is generated.

I can do it for the legend in Vb.net but struggling to add image to the control.  One way to do this is put a picturebox control on top of the chart but in this case, the logo is not part of the chart when the save chart function is called.  When a chart image is saved, I like to see the logo also be saved.

```
Me.Chart1.Legends("Legend1").CustomItems("0").Name = "Customer: "
Me.Chart1.SaveImage(dlg.FileName,DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Any suggestions... Would greatly appreciate if someone can share the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set a background image like so;

```
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).BackImage = "Background"
```

If that doesn't work for you, for can save the bitmap in memory;

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Chart1.Width, Chart1.Height);
Chart1.DrawToBitmap(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height));
```

Then put your new image over it and save it.